# Is it possible to create anonymous object with child as object as well in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, anonymous-objects

I want to create anonymous object in C#, and some its child is also object. Is it possible to do that in C#? (PS. I got some hint error for the following code)

```
var o = new { age = 123, child = { name = "asdffff"} };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the 'new':

```
var o = new { age = 123, child = new { name = "asdffff"} };
```

Comment: Thanks, mate. That's the answer for me. :)